# Описание провала аудита... сбивает с толку

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, аудит

Я тут [аудит](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/62178) завалил, обнаружив его природу ещё при попытке посмотреть историю правок, дабы понять в чём дело. Аудит довольно спорный, но речь не о том. Текст о провале:

> #### СТОП! Читайте и запоминайте.
>
> Данная проверка была нужна для того, чтобы оценить Вашу
> внимательность. **Вы не прошли проверку.** Качество данного сообщения
> очень хромает. Сообщение содержит бессмысленные оскорбления, чепуху,
> спам, явно не соответствует тематике или другие подобные недостатки —
> читатели сочтут его скорее непристойным или грубым, чем полезным. Если
> при проверке Вам попадаются подобные сообщения, их нужно **удалять** и
> **рекомендовать на удаление**.
>
> Не волнуйтесь, мы уже позаботились об этом сообщении. Пожалуйста,
> уделите минуту и внимательно изучите его, учитывая вышеприведённые
> инструкции.

...составлен так, что при его последовательном прочтении кажется, что в сообщении есть **вообще все** перечисленные проблемы. Возможно, стоит акцентировать внимание на том, что в сообщении есть ***одна из* перечисленных проблем**, и что для удаления достаточно **любой из них**.

Предлагаю подумать над тем, как изменить этот текст в лучшую сторону и предложить варианты в виде ответов к этому вопросу.

Comment: Этот ответ засыпали флагами о спаме, так что ничего удивительного, что он в аудит угодил.

Comment: @Qwertiy ссылка скорее для справки и иллюстрации того, насколько странно может выглядеть "Сообщение содержит бессмысленные оскорбления"... :)

Comment: Я один из тех, кто флаг спама поставил. В ревизиях видно, что ссылка изначально была через какой-то промежуточный ресурс. А так да, ответ более-менее съедобный...

Comment: С тем, что описание надо переформулировать - согласен.

Comment: @Qwertiy в ревизиях! Да! Я туда и полез и [получил 404](http://risovach.ru/upload/2014/05/mem/fraj_50999744_orig_.jpg).

Comment: Надо набирать 10К :)

Comment: С этим ответом ситуация довольно необычная - его, вопреки сообщению аудита, **можно** было исправить путём редактирования, что и [сделал](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/490027/revisions) Venzell. Поскольку теперь ответ нормальный, я снял отметки "спам" и восстановил его. Больше он не должен появляться в аудите.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> #### СТОП! Читайте и запоминайте.
>
> Данная проверка была нужна для того, чтобы оценить Вашу внимательность. **Вы не прошли проверку.** В этом сообщении есть серьёзные недостатки, которые вряд ли можно исправить путём редактирования. Подобными недостатками могут быть оскорбления, спам, текст без смысла или не по теме. Подобные сообщения бесполезны, а порой даже вредны. Если при проверке Вам попадаются такие, их нужно **удалять** и **рекомендовать на удаление**.
>
> Не волнуйтесь, мы уже позаботились об этом сообщении. Пожалуйста, уделите минуту и внимательно изучите его, учитывая вышеприведённые инструкции.

- Отдельно прокомментирую замену *чепухи* на *бессмыслицу*. *Чепуху* можно интерпретировать как **текст, содержащий фактические ошибки** (чепуху с **фактической** точки зрения), а это не повод для удаления сообщения: это повод для **голосов против**.

Comment: Отличная переработка текста.